# "Emulate" Nexus 7 on Galaxy Tab3 10 inch

Tags: android, android-emulator

In the same way as you are using a PC to emulate Nexus 7 (using AVD etc) it should be possible to "emulate" on a bigger tablet (replacing the PC).

The ordinary emulator is extremly slow on a not so new PC and you don't want to buy a new one. Besides the emulation on the tablet would be better with more correct OS, HW etc.

Does anyone know of a tool/app or methods for this? At least to verify the layout for various devices...

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the layout quite easily with Paranoid Android (a custom ROM). It allows you to change the dpi, therefore faking a different screen resolution.

Alongside with additional apps like IntentIntercept, and the usual sharedpref/db editor it has become invaluable in finding specific bugs in my app.

**Edit**: I noticed there are no PA-based Roms for your device (yet), so: forget about it...

I'd recommend you to have a look at [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) or the x86 images for the default emulator. For me (Laptop with dualcore @ 2.3Ghz) it's faster than the actual device (benchmark and smoothness)!

Comment: Don't think I can use x86 images on Windows because the machine has an AMD CPU and support for "Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx) extensions" is required.

Comment: Well, then I guess it's time for a new machine :) (depends what "not so new" means to you)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily emulate a Nexus 7 on a Nexus 10 with the "adb shell wm" command as described  [in this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/QhWQArNDfS3).

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. I will try it but it will take some time (must buy a tablet).